# How to make a field deselected and none viewing in Regular Experession (regex)?

Tags: regex, field, unselect, deselect

I want to write a regular expression for extract selected fields in a the one line:

for example with this line

```
(2017-11-01 time=14:07:41)
```

i want write a regex to extract below result:

```
2017-11-01 14:07:41
```

in other words i want to showing a one group (**2017-11-01 14:07:41**) without the "time=" characters.

Comment: what regex did you tried ???

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with 1 group. Regex groups can't "skip" over characters.

You can do it with 2 groups:

```
\((.*? )time=(.*?)\)
```

or simpler, use regex replace in your language:

```
Search: \((.*? )time=(.*?)\)
Replace: $1$2   (or \1\2 depending on your language/tool)
```

Comment: I want create CEF log format Parser for fortiweb device. how can i use "Regex Replace" in my parser?

Comment: What parameters does it take?

Comment: in the CEF Format i want to map extracted filed to the "endTime". the Standard format of endTime is : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" but in this case the "time=" character is annoying!

Comment: I'm not going to research "CEF format". Tell me the various functions/config and their parameters. Without knowing anything about "CEF format", I would use the "search" regex to find the hits and use the "replace" regex as the output. You must find how to apply those yourself.